# Fold the code only if file has more than 200 lines

Tags: vim, coding-style

I have default folding enabled in my `vimrc` file (indent method). I want to enable folding only if the file being opened has more than 200 lines.

How to make vim aware of it. The basic question is can I get the number of lines in vim when I open a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the number of lines in the buffer using the `line` function with a `'$'` parameter.

For example, `:echo line('$')` will show the line count in the status bar.

You should be able to use this in combination with `BufRead` to change your settings for each file you load based on its length.